# How do I grant raw disk access to a USB disk for a non-administrator in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virtualbox, permissions, virtualization

I want an account, which can not be in the Administrator group, to have direct access to `\\.\PhysicalDrive1`, which is an external USB disk. The disk may or may not contain partitions which is recognizable to Windows XP.

I have Administrator access to the machine to make the necessary setup, but I want to keep the user accounts which will do the actual access out of the Administrator group.

The closest information I have encountered regarding this is an article called [Setting Device Object Registry Properties After Installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563755%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN, which I reckon could be used to add information to the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CCS\Enum\USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_Xxx&Prod_Yyy&Rev_Zz` key in the Registry.

Comment: is driver installation out of bounds?

Comment: If you think of installing a custom driver which relay the requests, then it probably won't help in this case: I don't want to change the source code of the programs that need the access (VirtualBox, dd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the [magnificent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100268/373074) by [Oleg Kiriljuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) to another question (please go and vote him up!), I was able to figure out how to call [SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty](http://www.osronline.com/ddkx/install/di-rtns_18c2.htm) myself.

Thus, the [DskACL](http://kaufmann.no/roland/dskacl/) utility which provides a command-line front-end was born; the homepage describes how to use it. If anyone is interested in hacking further on it, I've also put up a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/RolKau/dskacl).